# AES encryption do not work on ARM processor

Tags: c, aes, armv8

I have a device with armv8 64 architecture and I want to use its instructions for accelerating AES. I found this code in Github which implements AES encryption:
https://github.com/noloader/AES-Intrinsics/blob/master/aes-arm.c However, it is missing decryption. I code it myself:

```
#if defined(__arm__) || defined(__aarch32__) || defined(__arm64__) || defined(__aarch64__) || defined(_M_ARM)
# if defined(__GNUC__)
#  include <stdint.h>
# endif
# if defined(__ARM_NEON) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#  include <arm_neon.h>
# endif
/* GCC and LLVM Clang, but not Apple Clang */
# if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__apple_build_version__)
#  if defined(__ARM_ACLE) || defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)
#   include <arm_acle.h>
#include <string.h>
#  endif
# endif
#endif  /* ARM Headers */

void aes_process_arm(const uint8_t key[], const uint8_t subkeys[], uint32_t rounds,
                     const uint8_t input[], uint8_t output[], uint32_t length)
{
    while (length >= 16)
    {
        uint8x16_t block = vld1q_u8(input);

        // AES single round encryption
        block = vaeseq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(key));
        // AES mix columns
        block = vaesmcq_u8(block);

        // AES single round encryption
        block = vaeseq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(subkeys));
        // AES mix columns
        block = vaesmcq_u8(block);

        for (unsigned int i=1; i<rounds-2; ++i)
        {
            // AES single round encryption
            block = vaeseq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(subkeys+i*16));
            // AES mix columns
            block = vaesmcq_u8(block);
        }

        // AES single round encryption
        block = vaeseq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(subkeys+(rounds-2)*16));
        // Final Add (bitwise Xor)
        block = veorq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(subkeys+(rounds-1)*16));

        vst1q_u8(output, block);

        input += 16; output += 16;
        length -= 16;
    }
}
void aes_decrypt_arm(const uint8_t key[], const uint8_t subkeys[], uint32_t rounds,
                     const uint8_t input[], uint8_t output[], uint32_t length)
{
    // Reverse the order of the subkeys
    uint8_t reversed_subkeys[rounds*16];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<rounds; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(reversed_subkeys+i*16, subkeys+(rounds-i-1)*16, 16);
    }

    while (length >= 16)
    {
        uint8x16_t block = vld1q_u8(input);

        // AES Final Add (bitwise Xor)
        block = veorq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(reversed_subkeys));

for (unsigned int i=rounds-1; i>0; --i)
{
    // AES single round decryption
    block = vaesdq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(reversed_subkeys+i*16));
    // AES inverse mix columns
    block = vaesimcq_u8(block);
}

// AES single round decryption
block = vaesdq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(reversed_subkeys));
        // AES single round decryption
        block = vaesdq_u8(block, vld1q_u8(reversed_subkeys+(rounds-1)*16));

        vst1q_u8(output, block);

        input += 16; output += 16;
        length -= 16;
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* FIPS 197, Appendix B input */
    const uint8_t input[16] = { /* user input, unaligned buffer */
        0x32, 0x43, 0xf6, 0xa8, 0x88, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x8d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x98, 0xa2, 0xe0, 0x37, 0x07, 0x34
    };

    /* FIPS 197, Appendix B key */
    const uint8_t key[16] = { /* user input, unaligned buffer */
        0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x9 , 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
    };

    /* FIPS 197, Appendix B expanded subkeys */
    __attribute__((aligned(4)))
    const uint8_t subkeys[10][16] = { /* library controlled, aligned buffer */
        {0xA0, 0xFA, 0xFE, 0x17, 0x88, 0x54, 0x2c, 0xb1, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x39, 0x39, 0x2a, 0x6c, 0x76, 0x05},
        {0xF2, 0xC2, 0x95, 0xF2, 0x7a, 0x96, 0xb9, 0x43, 0x59, 0x35, 0x80, 0x7a, 0x73, 0x59, 0xf6, 0x7f},
        {0x3D, 0x80, 0x47, 0x7D, 0x47, 0x16, 0xFE, 0x3E, 0x1E, 0x23, 0x7E, 0x44, 0x6D, 0x7A, 0x88, 0x3B},
        {0xEF, 0x44, 0xA5, 0x41, 0xA8, 0x52, 0x5B, 0x7F, 0xB6, 0x71, 0x25, 0x3B, 0xDB, 0x0B, 0xAD, 0x00},
        {0xD4, 0xD1, 0xC6, 0xF8, 0x7C, 0x83, 0x9D, 0x87, 0xCA, 0xF2, 0xB8, 0xBC, 0x11, 0xF9, 0x15, 0xBC},
        {0x6D, 0x88, 0xA3, 0x7A, 0x11, 0x0B, 0x3E, 0xFD, 0xDB, 0xF9, 0x86, 0x41, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x93, 0xFD},
        {0x4E, 0x54, 0xF7, 0x0E, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0xC9, 0xF3, 0x84, 0xA6, 0x4F, 0xB2, 0x4E, 0xA6, 0xDC, 0x4F},
        {0xEA, 0xD2, 0x73, 0x21, 0xB5, 0x8D, 0xBA, 0xD2, 0x31, 0x2B, 0xF5, 0x60, 0x7F, 0x8D, 0x29, 0x2F},
        {0xAC, 0x77, 0x66, 0xF3, 0x19, 0xFA, 0xDC, 0x21, 0x28, 0xD1, 0x29, 0x41, 0x57, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x6E},
        {0xD0, 0x14, 0xF9, 0xA8, 0xC9, 0xEE, 0x25, 0x89, 0xE1, 0x3F, 0x0c, 0xC8, 0xB6, 0x63, 0x0C, 0xA6}
    };

    /* Result */
    uint8_t ciphertext[19] = { 0 };
    uint8_t decryption[19]= { 0 };

    aes_process_arm((const uint8_t*)key, (const uint8_t*)subkeys, 10, input, ciphertext+3, 16);

    printf("Input: ");
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", input[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Key: ");
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", key[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Output: ");
    for (unsigned int i=3; i<19; ++i)
        printf("%02X ",ciphertext[i]);
    printf("\n");
        aes_decrypt_arm((const uint8_t*)key, (const uint8_t*)subkeys, 10, ciphertext+3, decryption+3, 16);


    printf("Decipher: ");
            for (unsigned int i=3; i<19; ++i)
                    printf("%02X ", decryption[i]);
        printf("\n");



    /* FIPS 197, Appendix B output */
    const uint8_t exp[16] = {
        0x39, 0x25, 0x84, 0x1D, 0x02, 0xDC, 0x09, 0xFB, 0xDC, 0x11, 0x85, 0x97, 0x19, 0x6A, 0x0B, 0x32
    };

    if (0 == memcmp(ciphertext+3, exp, 16))
        printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
    else
        printf("FAILURE!!!\n");
        if (0 == memcmp(decryption+3, input, 16))
                printf("Encryption SUCCESS!!!\n");
        else
                printf("Encryption FAILURE!!!\n");


    return 0;
}
```

But decryption and input message do not match. What I am missing?

Comment: How did you test that encrypt is correct?

Comment: Encrypt is correct according to FIPS 197 appendix B: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf

Comment: Note that you might not need AES decryption if you plan to use AES-CTR or AES-GCM, those use the algorithm only in one direction. If you want to debug this, I'd compare the subkeys and intermediate states with a known good implementation or existing intermediate values.

Comment: Just curious, are there any reasons why you are not using the [AArch64cryptolib](https://github.com/ARM-software/AArch64cryptolib) written by ARM and supporting hardware-assisted encryption/decryption ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending several days figuring out the proper way to implement AES encryption and decryption on an ARM processor, this is what I found.

Compared to your ***decryption*** implementation, it appears that **you are simply reversing the subKey array which is incorrect**.

When using *AES-NI* or *ARM NEON AES intrinsic*, the **original encryption round keys must first have InverseMixColumns applied to them**, in ARM we need to use the `vaesimcq_u8` intrinsic to apply the InverseMixColumn operation.

```cpp
size_t aes_rounds = Nr + 1;

round_key = new uint8x16_t[aes_rounds];
dec_round_key = new uint8x16_t[aes_rounds];

// NOTE: here the original key was placed in the first index
// so I did not apply inverse mix columns to it
// in your implementation you might need to apply it in the
// first index because you separated the original key with the subkeys.

round_key[0] = vld1q_u8(&subKeys[0]);
dec_round_key[0] = vld1q_u8(&subKeys[0]);

for (size_t i = 1; i < aes_rounds; ++i) {
    round_key[i] = vld1q_u8(&subKeys[i * 4 * Nb]);
    dec_round_key[i] = vaesimcq_u8(round_key[i]);
}

round_key[Nr] = vld1q_u8(&subKeys[Nr * 4 * Nb]);
dec_round_key[Nr] = round_key[Nr];
```

Regarding the implementation **for decryption, the pattern is exactly the same as encryption**.

Here is an example code for AES block encryption and decryption that you can use to check and compare with your decryption implementation.

```cpp
// AES block encryption using 128-bit key
void neon_aes128_encrypt(const uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output, const uint8x16_t *round_key) {
    uint8x16_t state = vld1q_u8(input);

    // Initial round
    state = vaesmcq_u8(vaeseq_u8(state, round_key[0]));

    // 8 main rounds
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        state = vaesmcq_u8(vaeseq_u8(state, round_key[i]));
    }

    // last 2 final round
    state = vaeseq_u8(state, round_key[9]);
    state = veorq_u8(state, round_key[10]);

    // store the result to output
    vst1q_u8(output, state);
}

// AES block decryption using 128-bit key
void neon_aes128_decrypt(const uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output, const uint8x16_t *dec_round_key) {
    uint8x16_t state = vld1q_u8(input);

    // Initial round
    state = vaesimcq_u8(vaesdq_u8(state, dec_round_key[10]));

    // 8 main rounds

    // note here that I did not reverse the dec_round_key
    // so I'm doing it from the last index to the starting index.

    for (int i = 9; i > 1; i--) {
        state = vaesimcq_u8(vaesdq_u8(state, dec_round_key[i]));
    }

    // final 2 rounds
    state = vaesdq_u8(state, dec_round_key[1]);
    state = veorq_u8(state, dec_round_key[0]);

    // store the result to output
    vst1q_u8(output, state);
}
```

If you compare the pattern with my given example above, notice that in your decryption implementation, you are doing an XOR right away and it looks like you reversed the encryption pattern, that is incorrect.

The correct way to decrypt the data is to first apply decryption then InverseMixColumns (like the usual round), then when you approach the second-to-last round, you apply a final decryption. Finally, for the very last round, you apply the XOR operation.